# Choose a random object

Tags: java, random

I'm new to Java, and I can't find the way to get or choose a random object from my list products. I tried so many different ways, but is always giving me an error.

```java
public class VendingWorking {
    
    List<Product> products= new ArrayList<>();
    
    public void registerProducts() {
        CStamp stampOne=new CStamp("1 Jan 2000", "Collectable Stamp");
        CStamp stampTwo=new CStamp("1 Jan 2000", "Collectable Stamp");
        CStamp stampThree=new CStamp("14 Feb 2000", "Collectable Stamp");
        CCoin coinOne= new CCoin("25 Jan 2019", "Collectable coin");
        Ccar carOne= new Ccar(2015, "Tin Car Toy");
        Ccar carTwo= new Ccar(2018, "Tin Car Toy");
        
        products.add(stampOne);
        products.add(stampTwo);
        products.add(stampThree);
        products.add(coinOne);
        products.add(carOne);
        products.add(carTwo);
    }

    public void getRandomElement(List<Product> products){ 
        Random random = new Random(); 
        Product index=products.get(random.nextInt(products.size())); 
    } 

    public List<Product> getRegProducts() {
        return products;
    }
}
```

Comment: and what is the error?

Comment: Since our telepathic skills are undeveloped please provide  exception coming from execution of your code

Answer (score 0):

You might want to change the return type of `getRandomElement` to either return an index or the Product. It's void right now. The other thing would be wary of your class variable names. You use products as a argument for the method.

```
public int getRandomElement(List<Product> p){ 
  return (int)(Math.random() * (p.size()-1));
}

public Product getRandomElement(List<Product> p){ 
  return p.get((int)(Math.random() * (p.size()-1)));
}
```

The first should return a random index the second an object. You might be having an indexing issue if you're scaling off the total list size.

Comment: IMHO his use of the Random class is cleaner than the one youre showing. You’re right with the return +1